# How to tell if $T(x,y,z) = (y \sin x, z \cos y, xy)$ is one-to-one and/or onto?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$T(x,y,z) = (y \sin x, z \cos y, xy)$ from $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$

To show 1-to-1, we want to show:

$$y \sin x = y' \sin x' \\
z \cos y = z' \cos y' \\
xy = x'y'$$

I'm not sure what to do here algebraically, since we can't divide anything since we don't know if $x, y, z, x', y', z'$ might be a $0$ value.

For onto, we want to solve for $x, y,$ and $z$:

$$y \sin x = a \\
z \cos y = b \\
xy = c $$

Again, we don't know if any of these values may be a $0$, so we can't be too careful in dividing by $0$. What should I do from here?

Comment: Take $x=0=z$ and let $y$ vary.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For 1-1, consider what you get when $x = 0$ and $z = 0$, and $y$ is any number. For onto, consider what happens to the first coordinate if you set the third coordinate to zero (i.e. $xy = 0$ so either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$).